# Differential equation solved by even monomials

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, combinatorics

> Suppose that for every $h=1, \dots, k-1$ the monomial $x^{2h}$ is solution of the following differential equation $$ a_1^{(k)} \left( x^{2h} \right)' + a_2^{(k)} x \left( x^{2h} \right)'' + \cdots + a_{k-1}^{(k)} x^{k-2} \left( x^{2h} \right)^{(k-1)} + x^{k-1} \left( x^{2h} \right)^{(k)} = 0.$$ Find the coefficients $a_j^{(k)}$, $j=1,\dots,k-1$, for every $k$.

---

In my attempt I've computed all the derivatives and found the equation

$$ 0 = a_1^{(k)}+(2h-1)a_2^{(k)}+(2h-1)(2h-2)a_3^{(k)} + \dots + (2h-1)\cdots(2h-k+2) a_{k-1}^{(k)} + (2h-1) \cdots (2h-k+1) $$
equivalent to
$$
0=a_1^{(k)}+(2h-1)\left[a_2^{(k)}+(2h-2)\left[a_3^{(k)}+...+(2h-k+2)\left[a_{k-1}^{(k)}+(2h-k+1)\right]...\right]\right].
$$
If you put $h=1$, it gives $a_2^{(k)}=-a_1^{(k)}$, for $h=2$ it gives $a^{(k)}_4=-a^{(k)}_3+a^{(k)}_1/3$ and so on. But I cannot find the general expression.

---

**Motivation**

Let $f,g$ be two functions related by $f(x):=g(x^2)$, then $f'(x)=2xg'(x^2)$ and so $$g'(x^2)=\frac{1}{2x}(f'(x)).$$
In the same way, $f''(x)=2g'(x^2)+4x^2g''(x^2)$, so $$g''(x^2)=\frac{1}{4x^3}(xf''(x)-f'(x))$$
and $f^{(3)}(x)=4x^2g^{(3)}(x^2)+12xg''(x^2)$, so $$g^{(3)}(x^2)=\frac{1}{8x^5}(x^2f^{(3)}(x)-3xf''(x)+3f'(x))$$
and so on. I hoped that $g^{(k)}(x^2)=0$ if and only if $g$ is a polynomial of degree $\leq k-1$, so I was interested in finding the coefficients of the equation solved only by even monomials.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $D$ be the derivative operator.

Note that $(xD-k)x^k=0$ and since $xD$ as an operator commutes with itself and $1$, we have $(xD-a)$ commutes with $(xD-b)$. This motivates us to consider $xD(xD-2)(xD-4)\dots (xD-(2(k-1))$. Applying this operator to any $x^{2i}$ for $i$ in $0,1,\dots k-1$ gives 0 and it has degree $k$ with leading coefficient $1$, so this is the polynomial we want.

Note that we can use that $Dx=xD+1$. For example $(xD)^2=x(xD+1)D=x^2D^2+xD$ and more generally $xD(x^nD^n)=x^{n+1}D^{n+1}+nx^nD^n $.

We can either expand the polynomial in terms of $xD$ and then simplify each term $(xD)^i$ into a sum of terms of the form $x^iD^i$ (the coefficients are Stirling numbers) or we can work iteratively. Let’s demonstrate that.

We have $xD(xD-2)=x^2D^2-xD$ giving initial coefficients of $1,-1$.

Multiplying by $(xD-4)$ gives:

$$(xD-4)(x^2D^2-xD)=(x^3D^3+2x^2D^2)-(x^2D^2+xD)-4(x^2D^2-xD)=x^3D^3-3x^2D^2+3xD$$

Thus, the next set of coefficients are $1,-3,3$.

Looking closely at the coefficients through these multiplications, we can derive a recursive formula for the coefficients: $$a_i^{(k)}=a_{i-1}^{(k-1)}-(2k-i-2)a_i^{(k-1)}$$

If we wasn’t an explicit formula, we can use the fact that the coefficients of $x(x-1)\dots(x-(k-1))$ are the signed Stirling numbers of the first kind and that the coefficients of $(xD)^k$ in terms of $x^iD^i$ are Stirling numbers of the second kind to get an explicit formula.

By https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_first_kind, we can write using signed Stirling coefficients of the first kind:

$$(x)_k=x(x-1)\dots(x-(k-1))=\sum_{i=0}^k s(k,i)x^i$$

Substituting $x/2$ and multiplying by $2^k$ gives:

$$x(x-2)\dots(x-2(k-1))=\sum_{i=0}^k 2^{k-i} s(k,i)x^k$$

From https://mathworld.wolfram.com/DifferentialOperator.html, it’s a known fact that for Stirling numbers of the second kind $S(a,b)$ we have:

$$(xD)^a=\sum_{b=0}^a S(a,b) x^bD^b$$

Combining these two formula gives us that

$$\sum_{j=0}^k a_j^{(k)} x^jD^j=xD(xD—2)\dots(xD-2(k-1)$$
$$=\sum_{i=0}^k 2^{k-i} s(k,i)(xD)^i$$
$$=\sum_{i=0}^k 2^{k-i} s(k,i)\sum_{j=0}^i S(i,j)x^j D^j$$
$$= \sum_{j=0}^k (\sum_{i=j}^k 2^{k-i} s(k,i) S(i,j)) x^j D^j$$

Thus, $a_j^{(k)}=\sum_{i=j}^k 2^{k-i} s(k,i) S(i,j)$.

For example the $5th$ row is $1,-10,45,-105,105$, so we should have that $a^{(5)}_3=45$.

Double checking the formula, we get $45$ as desired:
$$a^{(5)}_3=4 s(5,3)S(3,3)+2 s(5,4)S(4,3)+ s(5,5)S(5,3)$$
$$=4 \cdot 35 \cdot 1+2\cdot  (-10) \cdot 6 +  1 \cdot 25=140-120+25=45$$

Comment: Thank you very much. Is it possible to deduce a formula for the $a_j^{(k)}$, which is not recursive? Since, I don't think the coefficients are the Stirling numbers.

Comment: The coefficients of $x(x-2)(x-4)\dots(x-2k)$ are Stirling numbers of the first kind times a power of $2$, and the coefficients of $(Dx)^n$ are Stirling numbers of the second kind, so substituting $Dx$ into the first gives you an explicit formula as a double sum of Stirling numbers of the first kind times those of the second time times a power of 2. I have no idea if that can be simplified further.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't know much about Stirling numbers. For example, if $k=3$ you have $x(x-2)(x-4)(x-6)=x^4-12x^3+44x^2-48x$, giving coefficient 1,-12,44,48 and these don't seem to be Stirling numbers. 
While, for the coefficients $a_j^{(5)}$ my computations agree with your formula giving coefficients 1,-10,45,-105,105, but again these don't seem to be Stirling numbers or power of 2 of Stirling numbers. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Maybe, if we split the formula $a_i^{(k)}=a_{i-1}^{(k-1)}+ia_i^{(k-1)}-2(k-1)a_i^{(k-1)}$ the first part resemble the formula for Stirling numbers, but the last part ruins everything, right?

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_first_kind

4th row is 1 6 11 6. Multiplying by $2^n$ (since you’re using even numbers in the polynomial) gives $1,12,44,48$ as you’ve computed.

Comment: $(xD)^3=xD(x^2D^2 +xD)=x^3D^3+3x^2D^2+xD$ is the third row of Stirling numbers of second kind, $1,3,1$  https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind

Comment: Plug $xD$ into the polynomial and expand

Comment: But what about $1,-10,45,-105,105$, these are the coefficients with $k=5$. How do they come from Stirling numbers and power of $2$? Some of them aren't even even numbers.

Comment: I just added my formula to the solution itself.  That should make it clear that the $a’s$ are not Stirling numbers but sums of them.

Comment: Thank you for your help and the relation with Stirling numbers is very interesting. After your answer, in which you found the relation $a_j^{(k)}=a_{j-1}^{(k-1)}-(2k-i-2)a_j^{(k-1)}$, I asked also for the generating function of that sequence:https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4745931/generating-functions-of-recursive-sequence-with-two-parameters/4746376#4746376. That is an explicit formula that compute $a_j^{(k)}=\frac{(2n-k-1)!}{(k-1)!\,(n-k)!\,(-2)^{n-k}}$.

Comment: And is the converse also true? Namely, that if a function satisfies that differential equation, then it is a polynomial with only even power?

Comment: Should be. You have $k$ independent solutions (including $1$) to a degree $k$ equation. I could imagine there might be diff solutions on the left and right side of $0$ since the leading term becomes 0 at $x=0$ though.

Comment: You mean that I can write the equation above as $F(x,y(x),y'(x),...,y^{(k)}(x))=0$, with $F=\sum_{j=1}^ka_j^{(k)}x^{j-1}y^{(j)}(x)$ real analytic, then the space of solutions has dimension $k$ and a basis is $\{1,x^2,...,x^{2(k-1)}\}$?

Answer (score 1):

Hint.

$$
\sum_{k=0}^n a_k^h x^k\left(x^{2h}\right)^{(k+1)} = 2hx^{2h-1}\sum_{k=0}^n{a_k^h\prod}_{\nu=2h-1}^{\nu=2h-k}\nu = 0
$$

and so for $h=1,\cdots,n$

For $n=3$ and $h=1,\cdots,3$ we have

$$
\cases{
h=1\to a_0+a_2=0\\
h=2\to a_0+3a_1+6a_2+6a_3 = 0\\
h=3\to a_0+5a_1+20a_2+60a_3=0
}
$$

giving the polynomial

$$
p_3(x) = \left(1 + x-\frac{2 x^2}{5}+\frac{x^3}{15}\right)a_0
$$

Calling $\pi(k,j) = \prod_{i=k}^{i=j}i$ we have to solve for $p_n$ determination, the linear system

$$
M a = B a_0
$$

where

$$
a = (a_1,\cdots,a_n)'\\ B=-(1,\cdots,1)'
$$

and

$$
M = \{m_{ij}\}=\pi(2i-j,2i-1)
$$

Comment: And can you find the general $p_k(x)$?

Comment: I added a way to compute $p_k(x)$

Comment: I got a slightly different result, namely that $0=\sum_{j=1}^ka_j\pi(2h-j+1,2h-1)$. Btw, is $M$ invertible, is $M^{-1}$ explicitly given? Because, I would like a nice formula for the coefficient $a_k^{(k)}$ if there is one.