# Generating functions of recursive sequence with two parameters

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, generating-functions, moment-generating-functions

Suppose that we have the following sequence satisfying for every $n\geq1$ and $1\leq k\leq n$

\begin{array}{l}
f(n,k)=f(n-1,k-1)-(2n-k-2)f(n-1,k),\\\\
f(n,n)=1,
\end{array}
where we formally set $f(n,0)=0$, for every $n$.
Is it possible to find a generating function? Thank you for all the help.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: @ConMan I know that if there wasn't the term $(2-2n)f(n-1,k)$ it should be the Stirling numbers. But this is the first time I try to use generating functions.

Comment: There's a small issue in your definition that $f(n, 1) = f(n-1, 0) - (2n-3)f(n-1,1)$ but you haven't defined what $f(n, 0)$ is. Beyond that you can definitely analyse the sequence via generating functions.

Comment: Sorry, you are right. I have edited the question specifying $f(n,0)=0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I obtained : $\displaystyle \;\boxed{f(n,k)= \frac{(2n-k-1)!}{(k-1)!\,(n-k)!\,(-2)^{n-k}}}\quad$ for $\,1\le k\le n\,$ and $\,0\,$ else.

Short derivation for $1<k<n$ :
\begin{align}
f(n,k)&=\frac{(2n-k-1)!}{(k-1)!\,(n-k)!\,(-2)^{n-k}}\\
&=\frac {2n-k-1}{k-1}\frac{(2n-k-2)!}{(k-2)!\,(n-k)!\,(-2)^{n-k}}\\
&=\frac {k-1+2(n-k)}{k-1}\frac{(2n-k-2)!}{(k-2)!\,(n-k)!\,(-2)^{n-k}}\\
&=f(n-1,k-1)+\frac{2(2n-k-2)\,(2n-k-3)!}{-2(k-1)(k-2)!\,(n-1-k)!\,(-2)^{n-1-k}}\\
&=f(n-1,k-1)-(2n-k-2)f(n-1,k)\\
\end{align}

Generating functions may be found using [A001147](https://oeis.org/A001147) and others...

Comment: Thank you very much, that is what I was looking for. Do you recognize something familiar with the function obtained?

Comment: Here (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4740148/differential-equation-solved-by-even-monomials/4744141?noredirect=1#comment10069695_4744141) there is another way to give the coefficients as linear combinations of Stirling numbers.

Comment: Glad to simplify all this @GiulioBinosi and excellent continuation,

Comment: Is the solution unique? Or can be other solutions?

Comment: If we suppose that $f(n,k)=0$ for $k\le 0$ or $n\le 0$ then the solution provided is the only one. You may experiment this using the [pari/gp](https://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/download.html) scripts :  f(n,k)=if(k<=0 || n<=0,0,if(k==n,1,f(n-1,k-1)-(2*n-k-2)*f(n-1,k))) and  g(n,k)=(2*n-k-1)!/((k-1)!*(n-k)!*(-2)^(n-k)) for $\,1\le k\le n\,$

Comment: Thank you very much!